Running a script based on the computername
I am trying to write a PowerShell script to set an autologon account on a whole whack of computers, the issue we have is that the computers are in a variety of departments and each department has their own autologon account with unique password.
My initial thoughts were to get the script to lookup a CSV file with the account details in it but am running into some trouble doing so. to make matters worse the computer names are <PREFIX>-<ASSETNUMBER> so the csv would look something like:
CN,UN,PW
Purch,buyme,yuiop
HR,fireme,qwert
IT,fixmeplease,qazwsxedc
Manage,bossme,password

when the computernames are something like:
Purch-12345
HR-23456
IT-34567
Manage-45678

I have managed to split the computername
($Prefix =  $env:COMPUTERNAME.split("-")[0])
and am running this to search the csv:
$csv = Import-Csv .\import.csv 
$UserName = $csv.UN | where {$csv.CN -eq $prefix}
but all it does is list all the usernames in the table and not the one that corresponds to the $prefix variable
Google is not helping mainly because i don't know the terminology to use to search for the question

The pipe operator | acts a bit like a loop - it's enumerate the input objects and feed them, one-by-one, to the downstream cmdlet (in this case Where-Object).
You'll want to iterate over the entire $csv collection (so that you have access to both the UN and CN properties on each object), and then refer to each item in the Where-Object filter block with the special variable $_:
$UserName = $csv |Where-Object {$_.CN -eq $prefix} |ForEach-Object UN

The ForEach-Object call at the end will dereference the UN property on each object that came through the pipeline, and you should thus be left with the raw username string.

Credit to Powershell pipeline objects from import-csv headaches
The computer name of the machine I ran the following script on is FOOBAR
I placed my script and my import.csv file in c:\temp
My version of your import.csv file is
CN,UN,PW
Purch,buyme,yuiop
FOOBAR, myun, mypw
HR,fireme,qwert
IT,fixmeplease,qazwsxedc
Manage,bossme,password

PowerShell script:
clear-host

($computerName =  $env:COMPUTERNAME.split("-")[0]) | out-null
$userName = ""

$csv = Import-Csv -LiteralPath ("{0}\\import.csv" -f $PSScriptRoot)  

foreach ($item in $csv)
{
    if ($item.CN.ToLower() -eq $computerName.ToLower())
    {
        $userName = $item.UN
        break
    }
}

if ($userName.Length -ge 1)
{
    write-host ("Matched UserName is '{0}'" -f $userName)
}
else
{
    write-host ("CN '{0}' not found in {1}." -f $computerName, ("{0}\\import.csv" -f $PSScriptRoot))
}

The output of the script is:
Matched UserName is 'myun'
"Not found" test:
I removed FOOBAR, myun, mypw from import.csv and re-ran the script. The output of the script is:
CN 'FOOBAR' not found in C:\Temp\\import.csv.
